# Convert formatted date & time string to epoch time in Python

Tags: python, datetime-format, python-datetime

In python, I'd like to convert a formatted date + time + timezone string something like:

```
"Sat Jan 23 08:06:59 PST"
```

...to epoch time (or some other defineable format). I'm sure there is a simple way to do this that already exists, but after looking around in the `datetime` python library, I can't find exactly what I'm looking for. Any ideas on how this may be accomplished?

Comment: So what is your concrete desired output?

Comment: epoch time in seconds would be fine

Comment: Time zone abbreviations are ambiguous. [`PST`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_time_zone_abbreviations) could stand for Pacific Standard Time (UTC-08) or Philippine Standard Time (UTC+08).

Comment: The string doesn't have a year - what should the function assume?

Comment: what is PST in your case? Is it the local timezone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`datetime.strptime(date_string, format)` returns a `datetime` corresponding to `date_string`, parsed according to `format`. You can then use `datetime.timestamp()` to convert a datetime tuple to the epoch time.
For example:

```
from datetime import datetime

datetime.timestamp(datetime.strptime('Sunday, September 26, 2010 at 8:35 PM', "%A, %B %d, %Y at %I:%M %p"))

>>1285547700.0
```

Not sure how to convert the timezone accurately.

Comment: use `some_object.method()` syntax instead of `klass.method(some_object)` (Python allows both but you should always use the first one unless you have a very good reason to prefer another one). `.timestamp()` assumes the local timezone for a naive datetime object. There is no indication in the question that the input time is in the local timezone.

Comment: should read datetime.fromtimestamp

Answer (score -2):

Something like this?
(For Python 3.3+ - doc: https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html?highlight=re#datetime.datetime.timestamp )

```
import datetime
datetime.datetime.now().timestamp()
```

Comment: use `time.time()` instead of `datetime.now().timestamp()` (it is less convoluted and the former works even during DST transitions). Also, I don't see how it helps to convert `"Sat Jan 23 08:06:59 PST"` to "seconds since epoch" time.